# Mesh Network using Zigbee and Microcontrollers

Tags: zigbee

I would like establish a mesh network using Zigbee modules and ATmega8.
I need some basic c routines for establishing the network. My Controller is running with ATmega32. and end nodes will be on ATmega8.

I want plug and play wireless connection between Controller unit and nodes.

Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

The [Digi XBee series of RF modules](http://www.digi.com/products/wireless-wired-embedded-solutions/zigbee-rf-modules/zigbee-mesh-module/) is popular for plug and play wireless.  In it's simplest configuration, a pair of modules operates as a serial cable replacement, with bytes going in on one module coming out on the other.

If you want to have a multi-node network, you'll have to use the radios in API mode, where frames include a header with addressing information and checksum in the footer.  Digi has released an [ANSI C XBee Host Library](https://github.com/digidotcom/xbee_ansic_library) as Open Source on GitHub that could be a good starting point for that since you mention using C.  It looks like there's even a [fork of the library](https://github.com/Pastor/xbee_ansic_library/tree/benvironment) targeting the AVR platform.

Answer (score 0):

@user2031622, zigbee nowdays has builtin microcontroller such as CC2530 provided by TI stack (Texas instruments).CC2530 has a inbuilt 8051 microcontroller which supports mesh networking.

Comment: Please explain more. Your post likes a comment, not answer!